# How to measure user growth over time?

Tags: nodes

I have a client that is looking to measure how their drupal user accounts grow over time.

I currently have the http://drupal.org/project/chart module with the System Charts sub module enabled and this does provide a nice pie graph of the users as the system *currently* stands.

Has anyone found a solution for this? Integration with the charting API would be nice too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created),'%m-%Y') as month from users group by MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created));`. This uses the created field of the `users` table.

Edit:

In your code this should look something like

```
$result = db_query("SELECT count(*), DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created),'%m-%Y') AS month 
                    FROM {users} 
                    GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))");
```

This will return all new usercreations grouped by month. You could use other [Date/Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like DAY. But be carfull with the groups. The example above only works correct if you track the data of one year (because it does not group by year). Here is a more complex example:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT count(*), DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created),'%d-%m-%Y') AS month 
                    FROM {users} 
                    GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)),
                             MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), 
                             DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))");
```

I'm not entirely sure if there is a better solution to this. I can't help with the Integration into the charting API as I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the number of users regularly (for example once a day) into a database and then create a chart based on that.

Drupal does not keep that information.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Berdir; Drupal *does* track this information, though in a way that will take a bit of massaging. Check out the `{users}` table in the database; for each user account, the `created` column stores the [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of when the account was created. After exporting that data into a spreadsheet, functions could be written to count the number of accounts were created on or before any given day/week/whatever, and from there you have your graph. It'll be a bit of work, but all within the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Charts API has views integration so you could use a view in conjunction with an argument to display different months.  As Garrett Albright and nonsenz have said, you can use the Drupal users created dates and display them by the month they signed up.